# How to auto-select camera, based on selected marker in timeline editor?

Tags: python, timeline

I work a lot in the Timeline Editor. If I bind a camera to a Marker and it is named the same way, I thought that maybe I could have a script that auto-selects the corresponding camera after selecting the Marker. That would be so helpful to ease work with keyframes after selecting a Marker.

But in the *Info Panel*, selecting a Marker doesn't show any command. Also there is no Python tooltip after hovering over a Marker.

How to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Do you mean when selecting the marker at the bottom or is it ok if the camera gets selected based on a frame selected?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to trigger a script when directly clicking the marker, but here is an alternative way when going to a frame in the timeline. For example when you have a camera bound to frame $20$, you can click frame $20$  which would automatically select the corresponding camera:

```
import bpy

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()

def select_camera_from_marker(scene):
    current_frame = scene.frame_current
    
    for o in bpy.data.objects:
        o.select_set(False)

    for marker in scene.timeline_markers:
        if marker.frame == current_frame:
            scene.camera = bpy.data.objects[marker.camera.name]
            bpy.data.objects[marker.camera.name].select_set(True)
            break

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(select_camera_from_marker)
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me! :)
Your script selects camera in the outliner and 3D viewport, but doesn't selecting it in properties editor and the selection made this way don't update 3D View Side Bar parameters to the newly selected camera (I want to use side bar for quicker setting up animations)

If you know how to fix that I will be very happy :) !

Comment: Hi. Can you show screenshots of the "Properties Editor" and the "3D View Side Bar"? I'm not sure what you mean by those.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/Xn683R637vjQ.jpg

Comment: Do you want me to upload on yt short video? Maybe the screenshot and my early morning description of the problem isn't so easy to read :D I really can record ~1 minute video if it could help.

Comment: sorry im only on blender 3.4. there are no Properties Editor in my version so i can't help you with that.

Comment: It is an old feature, it's beeing shown in sidebar when you create custom property. But you can forget about side bar, in regular Properties Editor (the one with render tab, scene tab, material tab) using your script there is also lack of update when the camera is beeing selected by selecting binded keyframe, there also properties of object is not being refreshed. Just run your script and see that nothing changes there as you jump on different time markers.